# When i give the $error array the index of ['1'] it starts to begin with the index 1?? why is this happening?

Tags: php

```
<?php
echo "<pre>";
print_r($_POST);
echo "</pre>";

if(isset($_POST['calculate'])) {
    //  creating an array

    $error = array();


    if((isset($_POST['buyer']) && is_numeric($_POST['buyer'])) || (isset($_POST['seller']) && is_numeric($_POST['seller']))) {

        //  setting index
        $error ['buyer'] ['0'] = "the byer or seller is not numeric";
        $error ['seller'] ['0'] = "the seller is not numericc";
    } elseif((isset($_POST['buyer']) && !empty($_POST['buyer'])) || (isset($_POST['seller']) && !empty($_POST['seller']))) {
        $buyer = $_POST['buyer'];
        $seller = $_POST['seller'];
        // here the error comes
    } else {

        $error ['buyer'] ['1'] = "please input the buyer name";
        $error ['seller'] ['1'] = "please input the seller name";
    }

    if(empty($_POST['product'])) {
        $error ['product'] ['0'] = "Please select a Product";

    }
//   so finally print the array shows the index which i didn't want to start from  1

    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($error);
    echo "</pre>";
// the buyer associative array starts indexing from1

}


?>
```

Comment: 1. Show us result of `print_r($error)` line. 2. Why use numeric indices as strings?

Comment: Array
(
    [buyer] => Array
        (
            [1] => please input the buyer name
        )

    [seller] => Array
        (
            [1] => please input the seller name
        )

    [product] => Array
        (
            [0] => Please select a Product
        )

)

Comment: Well, why are you setting the index to `'1'` if you don't want it to start with 1?  Why not set it to something else?

Comment: @aynber but the assiciative array i need to have multiple keys...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because it's expected behavior. The observed behavior complies with the specification.

Reference: http://php.net/types.array

*excerpt:*

> The key can either be an integer or a string. The value can be of any type.
>
> Additionally the following key casts will occur:
>
> - Strings containing valid integers will be cast to the integer type. E.g. the key "8" will actually be stored under 8.